# NTFS partition resize taking an excessively long time, what can I do?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, kde, ntfs

On a 3TB Seagate Barracuda HDD, I had some free space which I wanted to allocate back to an NTFS partition. Using KDE Partition Manager I attempted to do so, and it's currently been running for over 21 hours and seems to be stuck at about 80%. The copy rate is excessively slow, at around 17 MiB/s (down from 43 MiB/s at the start which is still quite slow).

Is there anything I can do except wait it out for the extra 20 hours it will supposedly take? I've read that there's a very high chance of losing the entire disk if I cancel it, but at this rate I'm not convinced it's actually going to end as it keeps slowing down over time. I do have a backup but it only has important files (not the full disk) and isn't very recent, as I expected the operation to be relatively quick. The drive is also not a boot drive (just a storage one).

Here's the log from KDE Partition Manager:

```
Move partition ‘/dev/sdb2’ to the right by 250.00 GiB 
Job: Check file system on partition ‘/dev/sdb2’ 
Command: ntfsresize --no-progress-bar --info --force --verbose /dev/sdb2 
Check file system on partition ‘/dev/sdb2’: Success

Job: Set geometry of partition ‘/dev/sdb2’: Start sector: 524,322,816, length: 5,336,209,408 
Command: sfdisk --force /dev/sdb -N 2 
Set geometry of partition ‘/dev/sdb2’: Start sector: 524,322,816, length: 5,336,209,408: Success

Job: Move the file system on partition ‘/dev/sdb2’ to sector 524,322,816 
Copying 260,557 blocks (2,732,139,216,896 bytes) from 2,732,145,508,352 to 3,000,582,012,928, direction: right. 

Copying 40 MiB/second, estimated time left: 17:08:55 

Copying 40 MiB/second, estimated time left: 16:03:44 

Copying 41 MiB/second, estimated time left: 14:54:04 

Copying 42 MiB/second, estimated time left: 13:45:32 

Copying 42 MiB/second, estimated time left: 12:43:26 

Copying 43 MiB/second, estimated time left: 11:43:29 

Copying 43 MiB/second, estimated time left: 10:44:39 

Copying 35 MiB/second, estimated time left: 12:06:04 

Copying 28 MiB/second, estimated time left: 11:29:21 

Copying 17 MiB/second, estimated time left: 20:53:24
```

Comment: How long did it take finally? I am having the same trouble with a HDD of 4TB and trying to make a partition of 1TB and it is taking a lot a lot of time with low speed like. I also have a Seagate HDD.

Comment: @DannyHern I believe it ended up taking in the order of 3 days to finally complete, but that included the cancelling operation which I clicked half way through. Good luck :)

Comment: Finally I used Gparted and it does the partition in just a half hour.